# Creating a Registration form: In asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to Asp.net, and creating a online telephone bill payment form. A new user has to register to get a valid id,
In the SQL Server I created a table which has only two columns as Phone_number and User_name. I have set the Phone_number column as unique. Just to avoid re-registration of a user.

I have checked the form during runtime using asp.net web page but, i get some error in the code.

Also I have to display a message that "the phone number already exists."

my code is as follows. Is there a better way??

```
try
    {

        string s = " insert into new_user values(@Phone_number,@name)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Phone_number", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Name", TextBox2.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        MessageBox.Show("Phone Number already exist, Enter a different phone number");
    }
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox2.Text = null;


    Session["a"] = TextBox1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("registration.aspx");


}
```

in the above code if I don't user the Console.Writeline(); I get an error in the ExecuteNonQuerry() part.

Comment: Hi vikneshwar What is the error you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that First you check, Is there same phone no available in database? 
Just use select query , If you get any record you can display a message and if not exist any record then use insert query.

```
If(select * from table where phone=@Phone)
   insert command
else
   message
```